# PHP mixing zip and ftp stream wrappers

Tags: php, ftp, stream, zip

I can't figure out how to combine the zip:// and ftp:// stream wrappers.  I want to open read a stream to a file within a zip archive on a remote FTP server.

The following two work as expected; I can either open an FTP stream to the server or I can open a stream to a file within a zip archive.

```
fopen("ftp://user:pass@host/home/user/file.zip", "r");
fopen("zip://file.zip#file.txt", "r");
```

I'd like to combine the two and do something like.

```
fopen("zip://ftp://user:pass@host/home/user/file.zip#file.txt", "r");
```

But with that approach I get: failed to open stream: operation failed

Not sure how to find out what's causing the error, so I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: your trying to get a remote (zip) file from an ftp server ?

Comment: Trying to get the file inside the zip file, ultimately.  If I can do that with stream wrappers, it will be much more efficient.

Comment: get it out of or put it in? local or remote? this is an XY problem, you tell us your solution, but not what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: you can't concatenate & combine stream wrappers.

Comment: I want to read a file [hence the fopen(..., "r")].  I've updated the question to indicate this.

Comment: Instead use `PharData` to open it then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

```
<?php
copy('compress.zlib://ftp://username:password@ftphost.com:21/path/to/file.dat.gz', '/local/copy/of/file.dat');
```

works.

See http://ciaranmcnulty.com/simplifying-file-operations-using-php-stream-wrappers